# .scrollTop() a long overflow-y:scroll div

Tags: html, overflow, anchor, scrollto

I have a div with these settings:

`#check_in_history {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    top: 70px;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 20px;
    left: 0;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    padding: 20px 0 0 0;
}`

Basically, the div's height depends of the size of the browser window and changes when you resize it.

That div contains posts, and as users populate that list, it gets longer and longer.

I want to set it so that it automatically scrolls to the bottom of that list every time a user adds a post. I have a div with an ID at the bottom of that list, and I append the post .before() that div.

I have tried this function. It works for the first post entry, but as soon as you add a second one, it scrolls about 25% up the list.:

```
$("#check_in_history").animate({scrollTop: $('#scroll_target').offset().top}, 1000, 'swing');
```

id:check_in_history is the overflow:scroll div, and #scroll_target is the div at the bottom of that list.

How can I make it so that it always scrolls to that "target" div at the bottom of the list every time a new post is added?

Thanks for the help!